# MessagePack with nested Dictionary's and polymorphism

Tags: c#, nested, polymorphism, abstract, msgpack

I've been using MessagePackKnownCollectionItemTypeAttribute with e.g.

`[MessagePackKnownCollectionItemTypeAttribute( "MyAbstractBase", typeof( MyImpl ) )]
Dictionary<int, MyAbstractBase> class_member;`

this has worked great, but how about if I have:

`[MessagePackKnownCollectionItemTypeAttribute( "MyAbstractBase", typeof( MyImpl ) )]
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, MyAbstractBase>> class_member;`

The above won't work, I get "This operation is not supported because 'MyAbstractBase' cannot be instanciated." (at runtime, when I instantiate a serializer).
I also tried 
`[MessagePackKnownCollectionItemTypeAttribute( "MyAbstractBase", typeof( Dictionary<int, MyImpl> ) )]
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, MyAbstractBase>> class_member;`

That gave the same error.

Is there any way to handle abstract classes in nested dictionaries like that? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I ended up using an intermediary class:

```
public class MyIntermediaryDict
{
    [MessagePackKnownCollectionItemTypeAttribute( "MyAbstractBase", typeof( MyImpl ) )]
    public Dictionary<int, MyAbstractBase> intermediary_dict;
```

};

```
class MySerializableClass
{
    public Dictionary<int, MyIntermediaryDict> myDict;
}
```